# Applying color to dots in scatter plot according to a code in R

Tags: r, colors, scatter-plot

I am very new to R, and I have huge problems applying colors manually to the dots in my scatterplot according to a given code. The code is defined by letters (a, b, e, o, p, r, w, y) in my csv file in a column called "code".

I have tried for several hours adding this layer on my scatter plot (I will spare you for all the weird codes I've written during these hours).

My point is: I want to be able to tell the code, that if there is an "e" in the code column, then color the dot beige. If there is a "y", color the dot yellow....etc... I can manage to get color according to the letters in code, but it is not the colors that I define.

The colors I want:

```
scale_color_manual(code = c(a = "palegoldenrod", b = "tan3", e = "burlywood1", o = "darkorange1", p = "mediumorchid3", r = "red4", w ="ghostwhite", y = "goldenrod1"))
```

The csv file looks like this (has 88 rows in total):

```
size percentage code
 4.5       2.02    e
 4.5       2.72    e
 5.3       9.83    y
 4.1       0.45    w
 4.1       0.71    w
 4.0       0.46    w
```

My code so far is:

```
Data = read.csv("L:/Pseudoalteromonas/Genomecoverage/coverage2.csv", sep=";)

scplot <- ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=size, y=percentage, fill = code))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4)+
  geom_hline(size=1,aes(yintercept=7.5))
dev.off()
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: Look here http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Comment: should be `scale_fill_manual(values = c(a = "palegoldenrod", b = "tan3", e = "burlywood1", o = "darkorange1", p = "mediumorchid3", r = "red4", w ="ghostwhite", y = "goldenrod1"))`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
dt <- data.frame(x=seq(1,8),
                 y=seq(10,80,10),
                 code=c("a","b","e","o","p","r","w","y"))
ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = code))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("a" = "palegoldenrod", 
                              "b" = "tan3", 
                              "e" = "burlywood1", 
                              "o" = "darkorange1", 
                              "p" = "mediumorchid3", 
                              "r" = "red4", 
                              "w" ="ghostwhite", 
                              "y" = "goldenrod1"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-) It helped alot!